# I am using jquery and my event handler isn't being called

Tags: jquery

I am working on a website and I need to change some objects when a user clicks on them. Like if a user clicks on a box its color will be changed, I am using the following code but its not working, any suggestions?

```js
var divdbl = $( "div:first" );
divdbl.dblclick(function() {
  divdbl.toggleClass( "dbl" );
});
```

```css
div {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
 }
  div.dbl {
    background: yellow;
    color: black;
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
<span>Double click the block</span>
```

Comment: Just tested [ur code here](https://jsfiddle.net/ynaafaj5/). It works for me...

Comment: Your code works fine, please check are you missing some jquery libraries?

Comment: Check your jQuery libraries it's worked for me using jQuery 2.1.1 .

Answer (score 3):

Your code is working fine. Just forgot to include jQuery library. Include jQuery library inside code snippet to make it work by selecting jQuery version on first select dropdown :

```js
var divdbl = $( "div:first" );
divdbl.dblclick(function() {
  divdbl.toggleClass( "dbl" );
});
```

```css
div {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
 }
  div.dbl {
    background: yellow;
    color: black;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<span>Double click the block</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must include jquery library to your html code. Also put your jquery script inside `$(function(){...});` block this will ensure DOM is ready and apply event handler to the specified element.

```js
$(function(){
var divdbl = $( "div:first" );
    divdbl.dblclick(function() {
      divdbl.toggleClass( "dbl" );
    });
 });
```

```css
    div {
        background: blue;
        color: white;
        height: 100px;
        width: 150px;
     }
      div.dbl {
        background: yellow;
        color: black;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
    <span>Double click the block</span>
```